# Wordpress ACF true/false condition for all pages

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a `custom-field` of type `true/false` and I want some content to be displayed in the footer if true and not if false. Now the footer is visisble on all pages, so what kind of Rule do I have to set for the `true/false`-field? Should I make an footer options page instead?

I was thinking of having a "Show form in footer" true/false setting on the sidebar in the backend on the frontpage (pages->front-page)

Can someone maybe give me a good advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the field in option page so it will display as a separate section in admin panel and you can check the field into footer page by 
`<?php the_field('field_name', 'option'); ?>` so it will check the field value in option page..
 or you can set the field in front page and can check the field value in every page by passing the front page id as an argument in `the_field` like:-

```
$front_page = get_page_by_title('Front page name');
$pageid = $front_page->ID;
$footer =  get_field('about_banner_image',$pageid); 
if($footer == true)
{
   "Show footer"
}
```

**to use this in option page use "option" instead of $pageid in get_field**
we are getting the page id by using page name and passing that id into `get_field` or `the_field` so that acf will check the value of field into that page.. thus you can use it in any page by defining it into one page..

Comment: Happy to help :-)

Answer (score 3):

you should try like below: true/false save values 1/0

- you can create theme option from ACF plugin for this and get id of current 
  page.

  ```
  <?php 
      $field = get_field('your custom field ID/name',get_the_ID());

      if($field == '1'){
          echo 'content';
      }else{
          echo 'no content';
      }   
   ?>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

simple way you can do this by using a simple `wp_query`:

```
$footer_enable = get_posts(array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'enable_footer',
            'compare' => '=',
            'value' => '1'
        )
    )
));
if($footer_enable) {
   // show content
}
```

Comment: They are saved in `wp_postmeta` and  acf provides its own methods to for fetching values so no need to use custom query you can get the field value by using acf methods easily..